# $S_1\oplus S_2$ is a closed set?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $S_1=\{\lambda \mathbf d_1:\lambda\ge 0\}$ and $S_2=\{\lambda \mathbf d_2:\lambda\ge 0\},$ where $\mathbf d_1,\mathbf d_2$ are non-zero vectors in $\mathbb R^n.$

How to prove that $S_1\oplus S_2=\{\lambda_1d_1+\lambda_2d_2:\lambda_1d_1\in S_1,\lambda_2d_2\in S_2\}$ is closed?

Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks you

Comment: Do you mean "closed" in a topological sense, or closed under the addition / scalar multiplication? This looks like a Linear Algebra question, so I'm guessing the latter?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery the original statement said: prove that it is a closed convex set. The homework it's from a convex analysis course. So I think it is in a topology sense.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that a finite dimensional subspace is closed?

Comment: @copper.hat nop

Comment: @copper.hat is it a result from linear algebra or analysis?

Comment: @Anneliset.: It is a result from functional analysis, so I guess the answer is both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly more general result:

Suppose $D= \{ d_k \}_{k=1}^l$ is a finite set of points. Then
$K = \operatorname{cone} D = \{ \sum_k \lambda_k d_k | \lambda_k \ge 0\} $ is closed.

This result is a standard result, see, for example, Dem'yanov & Malozemov, "Introduction to minimax", Appendix II, Lemma 2.6.

Suppose $p_k \in K$ and $p_k \to p$. We would like to show that $p \in K$. It is clear that $0 \in K$ hence if $p =0$ we are finished, so we
can assume $p \neq 0$.

We can write each $p_k = \sum_i \lambda_i d_i$ with $\lambda_i \ge 0$.

The key result here is that for each $p_k \in K$ we can write $p_k = \sum_{i \in I_k} \lambda_i(k) d_i$ where $I_k \subset \{ 1,...,l\}$ is non empty,
the $\{ d_i \}_{i \in I_k}$ are linearly independent and $\lambda_i(k) \ge 0$ for $i \in I_k$.

Since the number of subsets of $\{ 1,...,l\}$ is finite, at least one
of the subsets $I_k$ occurs infinitely often, call this $I$. Then we have $p_{k_n} = \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i(k_n) d_i$ along this
subsequence.

Since the index set is fixed, we can let $\Delta$ be the matrix whose columns are formed from the $\{ d_i \}_{i \in I}$ and write
$p_{k_n} = \Delta \lambda(k_n)$, where $\lambda(k_n) \ge 0$ is a vector
of suitable dimension.

Since the columns are linearly independent, there is some $\alpha>0$
such that $\|D \lambda\| \ge \alpha \|\lambda \|$, and since
$p_{k_n} \to p$ we see that the $\lambda(k_n)$ are bounded and
hence converge along a further subsequence to some $\lambda \ge 0$.
Since $p = \Delta \lambda$, we see that $p \in K$.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if $d_1$ is a *positive* scalar multiple of $d_2$, then $S_1 = S_2 = S_1 \oplus S_2$. In that case, I leave you to use the below argument suitably.

Similarly, if $d_1$ is a *negative* scalar multiple of $d_2$, then I leave you to see that $S_1 \oplus S_2 = \{\lambda d_1 : \lambda \in \mathbb R\}$, for which you can again use the argument below suitably.

Now, if $d_1,d_2$ are linearly independent, we know that there exists a basis of $\mathbb R^d$, call  it $b_i$, which contains the vectors $b_1 = d_1$ and $b_2 = d_2$. Let us define the map $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^2$, given as follows : if $w = \sum w_ib_i ,$ then $f(w) = (w_1,w_2)$.

Note that $f$ is a  linear transformation, and hence a continuous function. Furthermore, the set in $\mathbb R^2$, given by $S = \{x \geq 0, y \geq 0\}$, is a closed set.

I claim that $S_1 \oplus S_2 = f^{-1}(S)$. I want you to prove this yourself.

Once this is done, $S_1 \oplus S_2$, being the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function, is also closed.

Comment: I will make the edit, you are correct.

Comment: $w_1,w_2$ are real numbers or vectors in $\mathbb R^n?$

Comment: $S_1 \oplus S_2 =\sum_{i=1}^k x_ib_i=f^{-1}(\{x\ge 0,y\ge 0\})= f^{-1}(S)?$

Comment: why do you introduce the concept of basis?