# Sum of a polytope and $\{\mu_jd_j:\mu_j\ge 0\}$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Is this proof correct?

> Let $S$ be a polytope in $\mathbb R^n,$ and let $S_j=\{\mu_jd_j:\mu_j\ge 0\}$, where $d_j\in\mathbb R^n$ is different from zero and $j=1,2,...,k$.Prove that $S\oplus S_1\oplus ... \oplus S_k $ is a closed convex set.

Proof:

(in a previous exercise I proved $S_1\oplus S_2$ is closed and convex)
So I have $S_1\oplus ... \oplus S_k $ is a closed convex set.

By another proved exercise I have that $S$ is a closed convex set.

The sum of convex sets is convex, so $S\oplus S_1\oplus ... \oplus S_k $ is convex.

Notice that $S=\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mu_jd_j\}=\{\mu_1d_1+...+\mu_k\}$ so it's elements $\mu_jd_j$ are like the elements of $S_j$. Thus $S$ can be taken as an element of this type $S_j$.

Therefore $S\oplus S_1\oplus ... \oplus S_k $ is a closed convex set.

Comment: Here is a short proof: A (Minkowki) sum of any number of convex sets is a convex set . The same if you replace "convex " by "closed".  You have just to argue about the convexity and closeness of the half lines $S_j$.

Comment: Think to erase in your text "$S=\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mu_jd_j\}$"

Comment: what will I write instead of $S=\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mu_jd_j\}?$

Comment: Nothing. this decomposition is of no interest in the context. The fact that $S$ is a polytope is not important for the question. Retain only the fact that a polytope is a closed convex set.  I stop now (22:40 CET).

Comment: I answered this in your other question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2474416/27978

Comment: I don't understand your question. The set $\{ \sum_k \lambda_k d_k | \lambda_k \ge 0 \}$ is a closed convex cone. (For a finite collection of $d_k$.)

Comment: @copper.hat ok but in this exercise I wanted to show that the direct sum of cones + a polytope is a closed convex set

Comment: Note that the sum of closed convex sets is not necessarily closed, for example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/712188/27978.

Comment: A polytope is compact, and the sum of a closed and compact set is closed.

Comment: @copper.hat I know, I already have the proof that shows this particular sum of closed convex cones is a closed convex set

Comment: @copper.hat but the problem remains when I add the polytope to the cones, the problem is if they are still closed when I sum them. Do you see it?

Comment: @copper.hat I already understand your previous comment..ok so problem solved. now the result 'the sum of a closed and compact set is closed.' is from analysis, right?

Comment: The cone $K= \oplus_k S_k$ is closed and convex. The set $S$ is compact and convex. Then the set $S + K$ is closed and convex.

Comment: It is straightforward to show that the sum of compact & closed is closed using sequences.

Comment: @copper.hat why $S$ is bounded? Intuitively could you explain why?

Comment: I presume by polytope you mean the convex hull of a finite number of points? If so it is straightforward to show that any convex combination is bounded by the maximum norm of the elements in the set.

Comment: @copper.hat  So could I say that $S$ it is bounded because if I take the maximum norm of the convex combination will be bounded?

Comment: You can prove it yourself. If $\|d_k\| \le K$ then $\| \sum_k \lambda_k d_k \| \le \sum_k \lambda_k K = K$.

Comment: @copper.hat oh ok I understand the proof but I don't see why can you take this $\|d_k\| \le K$ as hypothesis?

Comment: How do you define a polytope?

Comment: @copper.hat is the convex hull of a finite number of points,

Comment: A finite set is bounded.

Comment: ooh ok now everything is clear, thank you @copper.hat